# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2: database tool issues

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA to manage both my Python code and Postgres databases, without issue, until about 4h ago.

**The problem**:

- I cannot "refresh" the database. (A) in the image.
- I cannot "delete" or "drop" tables from the database. (B) in the image.
- I did not try creating tables.

I can, however, read data from tables...

[image]

Background Tasks displays a perpetual progress bar, usually stuck on "indices". Image below.

[image]

I have tried invalidating the cache, deleting cache files, restarting the database server, giving the server more memory, etc.

Does anyone have any idea (no pun intended)?

Comment: just tried with my own IntelliJ and PostreSQL installation, no problems. If restarting things doesn't work, check if there's anything in log files and contact Jetbrains support.

Comment: Try Database Tools | Forget Cached Schemas action from the data source context menu. Then Synchronize the data source again. It may also help to re-create the data source from scratch (not using "clone" button).